# Smallest multiple of a number that gives a specific remainder modulo another number

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given three positive integers $a, b$ and $c$, my task to find the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $(k * a) \mod b = c$.
I can obviously try values of $k$ from $1$ and higher, until I find the right value. My question is, can this computation be done in $O(1)$ time? That is, is there a direct way to calculate the smallest integer value of $k$ such that $k*a - c$ is a multiple of $b$?

Comment: You need modular inverse of k mod b which is O(log k log b) computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Congruent Modulo Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation), one can rewrite the problem as:

$$a*k \equiv c\pmod{b}$$
This is a simple linear congruence, that can be solved using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)

There are other algorithms, but this one is the simplest.

According to Wikipedia:

> In big O notation, this algorithm runs in time $O(\log(m)^2)$, assuming
>   $|a| < m$, and is considered to be very fast and generally more
>   efficient than its alternative, exponentiation.

Where $m$ is the letter $b$ in your example

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you mean O(log(m)^2) for the running time ?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I have fixed that in my answer.